# How to trigger handle_info due to timeout in erlang?

Tags: server, erlang, timeout, erlang-otp

I am using a gen_server behaviour and trying to understand how can `handle_info/2` be triggered from a `timeout` occurring in a `handle_call` for example:

```
-module(server).
-export([init/1,handle_call/3,handle_info/2,terminate/2).
-export([start/0,stop/0]).

init(Data)->
    {ok,33}.
start()->
   gen_server:start_link(?MODULE,?MODULE,[]).
stop(Pid)->
   gen_server:stop(Pid).

handle_call(Request,From,State)->
     Return={reply,State,State,5000},
     Return.

handle_info(Request,State)->
    {stop,Reason,State}.

terminate(Reason,State)->
    {ok,S}=file:file_open("D:/Erlang/Supervisor/err.txt",[read,write]),
    io:format(S,"~s~n",[Reason]),
    ok.
```

**What i want to do**:

I was expecting that if I launch the server and would not use `gen_server:call/2` for `5` seconds (in my case) then `handle_info` would be called, which would in turn issue the `stop` thus calling `terminate`.
I see it does not happen this way, in fact `handle_info` is not called at all.

In examples such as [this](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors#using-supervisors) i see the `timeout` is set in the return of `init/1`.
What I can deduce is that it `handle_info` gets triggered only if I initialize the server and issue nothing (nor `cast` nor `call` for `N` seconds).If so why I can provide `Timeout` in the `return` of both [handle_cast/2](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_cast-2) and [handle_call/3](https://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3) ?

**Update**:

I was trying to get the following functionality:

1. If no `call` is issued in `X` seconds  trigger `handle_info/2`
2. If no `cast` is issued in `Y` seconds trigger `handle_info/2`

I thought this timeouts can be set in the `return` of `handle_call` and `handle_cast`:

```
{reply,Reply,State,X} //for call
{noreply,State,Y}   //for cast
```

If not, when are those timeouts triggered since they are `returns`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To initiate timeout handling from [`gen_server:handle_call/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_call-3) callback, this callback has to be called in the first place. Your `Return={reply,State,State,5000},` is not executed at all.

Instead, if you want to “launch the server and would not use `gen_server:call/2` for 5 seconds then `handle_info/2` would be called”, you might return `{ok,State,Timeout}` tuple from [`gen_server:init/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:init-1) callback.

```erlang
init(Data)->
    {ok,33,5000}.
```

---

You cannot set the different timeouts for *different* calls and casts. As stated by Alexey Romanov in comments,

> Having different timeouts for different types of messages just isn’t something any `gen_*` behavior does and would have to be simulated by maintaining them inside state.

---

If one returns `{reply,State,Timeout}` tuple from any `handle_call/3`/`handle_cast/2`, the timeout will be triggered if the mailbox of this process is empty after `Timeout`.

Comment: I do not understand.If i put a timeout in `init/1` return , shouldn't that mean that if i do not call anything (call nor cast in given interval ) it will get triggered? What if i want different timeouts for not calling `call` and `cast`  for example : `5000` for not calling `call` and `3000` for not calling `cast`? Also once i used `call` and it enters `handle_call` when does that timeout trigger ? If the caller does not get the reply in given timeout  or how ?

Comment: I don't think that works for what he asks (if _I_ understand correctly). Instead the effect will be that one of the timeouts will be used depending on which of `call` and `cast` is handled later. Having different timeouts for different types of messages just isn't something any `gen_*` behavior does and would have to be simulated by maintaining them inside state.

Comment: I have understood the part with the `init/1` but then again i do not get when would a `timeout` from a `handle_call/cast` return trigger then?

Comment: If one returns `{reply,State,Timeout}` tuple from any `handle_call/3`/`handle_cast/2`, the timeout will be triggered if the mailbox of this process is empty after `Timeout`.

Comment: So basically you are saying that if  i issue a `call/2` , and the `handler` handles it with `{reply,State,Timeout}` , if i the issuer do not get the reply in `Timeout` then `handler` gets notified and proceeds to `handle_info` ?

Comment: `handle_info/2` with `Request=timeout` will be called by VM if there was no message received by this `gen_server` within a timeout.

Comment: So what happens after `Timeout` in the aforementioned scenario ? What gets called  after `{reply,Reply,State,Timeout}` in `handle_call/3` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not follow. What “aforementioned” scenario? `{reply,Reply,State,Timeout}` is what `handle_call/3` _returns_, nothing might ever _be called_ after. If one returns any `{__, Timeout}` tuple from `call/2`/`cast/2` **and no message is sent to this process in `Timeout` (read: no `call`/`cast`/`!` was issued with this `gen_server` as a recipient**, VM would send a message `timeout` to it, which might be handled with `handle_info(timeout, _State)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205212/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-aleksei-matiushkin).

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you read source code:gen_server.erl

```
% gen_server.erl 
% line 400
loop(Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, HibernateAfterTimeout, Debug) ->
  Msg = receive
          Input ->
            Input
        after Time ->
      timeout
        end,
  decode_msg(Msg, Parent, Name, State, Mod, Time, HibernateAfterTimeout, Debug, false).
```

it helps you to understand the parameter Timeout